# Only disable scroll down when two div collide css

Tags: javascript, css

The question is whether it would disable only the scrolldown when two div collide between in css.

Comment: Please can you add more information... including the context of your problem, and a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have already solved. 
In future I will doubt further explanation and code for the question is more complete. Thank you very much again